# JavaScript Canvas libraries slow, don't use GPU?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, canvas

I am developing a graphical flow chart kind of application where I link together "modules" which the user can drag around and what not. I'm using libraries like draw2d (which uses raphael.js, for example) that use SVG and HTML5 canvas to do the graphics.

However, I'm not even approaching what I would consider "stress" levels just yet and it's running ridiculously slow in my browser. When I drag the modules (blue boxes), it feels like 10 frames per second, or even less. Screenshot to show what I have on screen:

[image: Sample shot of my application. Dragging the big rectangles is really slow..]

On my laptop I have a System Monitor provided by AMD showing what percentage of my CPU cores and GPU is being used. When I drag the objects, my CPU cores (all 4 of 'em) get used up to the max, but the GPU doesn't get used at all.

Are graphics-based web frameworks not using the GPU? Given what my application is trying to do and the poor state it's currently in performance-wise, is it likely that I'll have to find a new graphics library that uses openGL or something? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: This would depend upon a *particular implementation*, no? (And I do not see any *implementations* mentioned in the post. I would not be surprised to see significant performance differences/characteristics between different browsers.)

Comment: I was just going to update the OP - if it helps, I tested in Firefox and found out it was much worse. I'm talking like 2 frames a second...

Comment: I can say that with Fabric.js, this amount of text, boxes and lines would be pretty snappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the library and used browser. If you use chrome the first step is to go to chrome://gpu and see what features are enabled for GPU acceleration. Then it purely depends on 2D framework library if it is using standard canvas drawing functions or implements own software rendering functionality.

Comment: I checked, and it said I have everything hardware accelerated. Could it be a difference between using SVG and Canvas? In either case... I'm considering moving my application out of the browser.

Comment: It really does depend on how your libraries use canvas. If your lib is using SVG go to chrome://flags and check if SVG acceleration is enabled. If your lib is drawing to canvas then it should be based on drawing triangles and simple shapes. Filling open shapes and shapes made of bezier curves will be most likely software rendered.